# Cause of undeclared entity warning using nusoap and asmx?

Tags: php, web-services, asmx, nusoap

I'm writing a php client for an ASP.Net web service. When I run, I get:

```
wsdl error: XML error parsing WSDL from https://ctechgames:443/Service1.asmx on line 99: Undeclared entity warning
```

after making the call. I'm pretty new at this, and I really don't know what I'm doing.

Request and response are both empty. I don't know what's going on, or why. Here's my client code:

```
$client = new nusoap_client("https://ctechgames:443/Service1.asmx",
                        array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$schoolName = $client->call('GetSchoolName', array() );
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Changed the code to the following:

```
$client = new nusoap_client("https://ctechgames:443/Service1.asmx?wsdl",
                        array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$schoolName = $client->call('GetSchoolName', array('parameters' => array()) );
```

The `?wsdl` gets the wsdl from the website, instead of the html for access from a web browser. The `'parameters' => array()` is just something .Net web methods want, based on the way it parses the parameters.

Hope this helps someone out there!